# Select count of occurrences of each status in another table using jpa criteria

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I need to select my main table and the number of occurrences of each status in another table using criteria api in just one query.

My current solution is in native query, which is working, but I want to do it in a more object-based way. 
I tried doing it in criteria by using a specific query just to select all status and then count it manually. But with that approach, I'm calling two queries: One to fetch the details in my main table, and another to select all status where the id is same with main table.
Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Here is my native query (simplified):

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT a.id, a.type, b.count_pending, b.count_failed, b.count_processed
FROM CM AS a
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
 COUNT( CASE WHEN status = 'PENDING' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) count_pending,
 COUNT( CASE WHEN status = 'FAILED' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) count_failed,
 COUNT( CASE WHEN status = 'PROCESSED' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) count_processed
 FROM CM_PARAM WHERE id_cm = :cmId
 GROUP BY id_cm    
) AS b ON a.id_cm = b.id_cm
WHERE a.id_cm = :cmId) AS a
```

Here is my CM entity (simplified):

```
@Entity
public class Cm {

  @Id
  private Long idCm;

  private String type;

  // other fields
  // setters and getters

}
```

Here is my CM_PARAM entity (simplified):

```
@Entity
public class CmParam {

  @Id
  private Long idCmp;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_cm")
  private Cm cm;

  private String status;

  // other fields
  // setters and getters
}
```

Using the native query approach, I can add transient fields in my Cm entity:

```
@Transient
private Long countPending;

@Transient
private Long countFailed;

@Transient
private Long countProcessed;
```

How can I do it using criteria api, and if possible in just one transaction.

The expected output would be somehow like this:

```
{
  "idCm": 1,
  "type": "sms",
  "countPending": 5,
  "countFailed": 3,
  "countProcessed": 9
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query can be rewritten without the subquery join:

```
SELECT
    a.id_cm,
    a.type
    COUNT(CASE WHEN b.status = 'PENDING' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) countPending,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN b.status = 'FAILED' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) countFailed,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN b.status = 'PROCESSED' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) countProcessed
FROM CM AS a
LEFT JOIN CM_PARAM AS b ON a.id_cm = b.id_cm
WHERE a.id_cm = ?1
GROUP BY a.id_cm, a.type
```

You will have to add the inverse side of the association to `Cm`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cm")
private Set<CmParam> params;
```

(otherwise, you would need a `RIGHT JOIN` from `CmParam` to `Cm`, something Hibernate does not support)

The Criteria query then becomes:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<? extends Object[]> cq = cb.createQuery(new Object[0].getClass());

Root<Cm> a = cq.from(Cm.class);
Join<Cm, CmParam> b = a.join("params", JoinType.LEFT);
cq.where(cb.equal(a.get("idCm"), cb.parameter(Long.class, "idCm")));
cq.groupBy(a.get("idCm"), a.get("type"));
cq.multiselect(
        a.get("idCm"),
        a.get("type"),
        cb.count(cb.selectCase()
                .when(cb.equal(b.get("status"), "PENDING"), 1L)
                .otherwise(cb.nullLiteral(Long.class))),
        cb.count(cb.selectCase()
                .when(cb.equal(b.get("status"), "FAILED"), 1L)
                .otherwise(cb.nullLiteral(Long.class))),
        cb.count(cb.selectCase()
                .when(cb.equal(b.get("status"), "PROCESSED"), 1L)
                .otherwise(cb.nullLiteral(Long.class))));
```

Note that the result is of type `Object[]`. If you want to use your current approach with transient fields, the easiest way would be to add the appropriate constructor to `Cm` and use the `cb.construct()` method:

```
cq.select(cb.construct(Cm.class, a.get("idCm"), a.get("type"), ...))
```

Note that:

- if you'd rather not add the `params` field to `Cm`, but you're fine with an `INNER JOIN`, you can just use `Root<CmParam> b = cq.from(CmParam.class)` and `Join<CmParam, Cm> a = b.join("cm")` instead.
- if in your actual query you're selecting more attributes from `Cm` than just `cmId` and `status`, you will probably need to list them all in `groupBy` as well

Comment: Thank you!! Especially with the query rewrite. I don't know why I chose the hard way with that subquery.